Mean ergodic Operators
I am currently listening to some functional analysis lecture and solved the following exercise:
Let E be a Banach space, $T,S:E\rightarrow E$ bounded linear Operators, such that $\exists k \in \Bbb N:S^k=T $.
If: $\sup_{n \in \Bbb N} \Vert T^n \Vert \in \Bbb R $ and $T $ is mean ergodic
$ \implies \sup_{n \in \Bbb N} \Vert S^n \Vert \in \Bbb R $ and $S $ is mean ergodic
PS: T is defined to be mean ergodic if and only if $$\forall x \in E: \lim_{N\to \infty} \frac 1N\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}(T^i(x)) \in E$$ (converges in the Norm of E)
My question is: Does 'the other direction' hold too? Is this an equivalence?
It seems very likely to me, but i could not proof the mean ergocity. For reflexive spaces its true since $T$ is power bounded, but in the general case i have no idea.

It would be useful to to add the definition of a mean ergodic transformation.

No its not an equivalence, i.e. the statement:
$$T \text{ mean ergodic }\implies  T^n \text{ is mean ergodic}$$
(for $n\in \mathbb N, T$ a bounded linear operator) is wrong in general.
To see this take the multiplication operator $M_a: \ell^{\infty}\to \ell^{\infty}, x\mapsto a\cdot x$, for $a:= (\frac {1-n}n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$. $M_a$ is clearly linear and bounded with $\|M_a\| = \|a\|_{\infty}$, remember: $(\ell^{\infty}, \|\cdot \|_{\infty}),$ bounded complex sequences with sup-norm, is a banach space.
Now, for $x\in \ell^{\infty}, N \in \mathbb N:$ $$\frac 1 N \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}(M_a)^k(x)=\frac 1 N \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}a^k\cdot x =x\cdot (\frac 1 N \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N} \in x\cdot (\frac 1 N \cdot[-2,1]^{\mathbb N})$$
as one can see by the basic partial sum formula of geometric sequences.
It follows:
$$\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac 1 N \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}(M_a)^k(x)= 0, \text{ for any 
 }x \in \ell^{\infty}$$
the mean ergodicity of $M_a$. But with the same argument one gets:
$$\frac 1 N \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}(M_a)^{2k}(x)=x\cdot (\frac 1 N \cdot \frac{n^2(1-(\frac {n-1} n)^{2N})}{2n -1})_{n\in N}$$
which converges pointwise to zero (for $N \to \infty$). But, choosing $x=(1)_{n\in \mathbb N}$:
$$\|\frac 1 N \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}(M_a)^{2k}(x) \|_{\infty}= \| (\frac 1 N \cdot \frac{n^2}{2n-1}\cdot\frac {n^{2N}-(n-1)^{2N}}{n^{2N}})_{n\in \mathbb N} \|_{\infty} \geq 2$$
since
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac 1 N \cdot \frac{n^2}{2n-1}\cdot\frac {n^{2N}-(n-1)^{2N}}{n^{2N}}=2$$
as one can check by hand. This gives us the non-norm convergence, hence $(M_a)^2$ can't be mean ergodic.
